# error with @MvcHtmlString.Create(...)) - system.web.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I create a new asp.net mvc 4 version and 
include dotnetopenauth implementation from Nerddinner project into it.

registration and authentication using formsauthentication works ok. On 
the other hand when I include Logon details for openauth - 
logonopenid.cshtml - implementation I received an error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not 
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) "

Source Error:

```
Line 38: @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(options, 
null))
```

I checked and I´m using system.web.mvc version= 4 and includes a 
definition for mvchtmlstring and html helpers includes a definition 
for openidselectorscripts. truly I dont know why is requesting 
assembly 1.0.0. 
any help will be appreciated. brgds, 
sebastian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to your web.config file:

```
<runtime>
    <!-- When targeting ASP.NET MVC 4, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 references relink
         to MVC 4 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it. -->
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: great, thank you so much... In my case it was that statement but included in
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </dependentAssembly> I dont know why system.web.mvc was included again inside system.web.webpages too. I commented that area and worked ok. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

sebastian_h,

I've seen this happening before. 'distant' memory recalls the issue being related to entries in the web.config that is located under the /Views folder (as opposed to the root web.config file).

I may be way off here, but this rings a bell. Certainly worth a quick peek.

Comment: thanks @jim I will check if I found any inconsistency on web.config located inside views.